# Implementing other comparison operators in terms of operator< in one call

Tags: c++, comparison

I've seen that, if you have `operator<`, you can implement, say, `operator>=` as `!(a < b)`. However, when I went to the C++ Committee in Bristol, they said that you can implement *all* the comparison operators this way. Particularly, when considering types which have non-trivial comparison operators (consider an arbitrarily long string, especially if this is Unicode), this can be done with only one call to `operator<`. I cannot conceive of how this could be done.

How can I implement `operator>` and `operator<=` with just one call to `operator<` and none to the other comparison operators?

Comment: I am not sure abt just `<` but [`std::rel_ops`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp) can do them with `==` and `<`

Comment: The same as your own example: `a > b` is equal to `!(a == b || a < b)`. One call to operator<.

Comment: That involves one call to operator== as well, which would clearly be less performant than a custom operator>.

Comment: As I said, it's one call to operator< -- exactly as requested. An answer that you didn't expect may be because of the wording of your question.

Comment: @Jongware: Yes. My example showed that I wanted something performance-sensitive, but the wording only clearly stated operator<, whereas I actually meant that all the provided operators should be considered as slow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `a > b == b < a`
- `a <= b == !(b < a)`
- `a >= b == !(a < b)`

It's even possible to implement equality in terms of less than (Kind of abusing my meta-syntax here):

- `(a == b) == (!(a < b) && !(b < a))`
- `(a != b) == (a < b || b < a)`

Although I wouldn't suggest doing so in practice, since it requires two comparisons and can generally be implemented more efficiently directly.

Comment: I had seen :-) I removed the comment

Comment: This clearly doesn't work if one wants to implement three-state logic as in SQL

Comment: +1 And the last one... (!(a < b) && !(b < a)) you could !((a < b) || (b < a)) one less negation

Comment: This is friggin genius but I must point out, the last 1 is 2 calls, not 1

Comment: @KarthikT True - I threw that last in mostly to show it is *possible* to implement equality in terms of less-than, not necessarily to suggest it's a good idea to do so.

Comment: You're right, but I only strictly asked for operator> and operator<=. I did, however, make good use of the provided operator== implementation as well. I had intended to simply look that up later.

Comment: @DeadMG: For extra credit, consider how to avoid having to write all those operators for each type you define...

Comment: @David: Implement it as the default as part of my custom language. Problem solved.